# µVISION: BUILD TARGET ALWAYS RECOMPILES ALL FILES

Tags: keil, rebuild, recompile, armcc

µVision v.5.01 retranslates all files in my project when I'm using Project - Build target. However, I have made no changes to my files and the the µVision built-in MAKE should check the timestamp to see that there are no changes. I have made sure TZ is not defined anywhere, that Create Batch File is not checked, and Use Cross-Module Optimization is not checked. C Compiler Listing and C Preprocessor Listing are not checked too.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was simple: my Project Target name contained a slash. When I removed it everything started to work just fine.